# HTTP ERROR 500 while querying mysql database with php in html

Tags: php

I am putting this php code inside my html file and getting "DOMAIN is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500"

```
 <?php
session_start();
$unames = $_SESSION['username']
$link = mysql_connect( "localhost", "databaseusername", "databasepassword");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);
$vipquery = mysql_query("SELECT vip FROM tablename WHERE username = '$unames'", $link);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($vipquery)) {
    $vips = $row['vip'];  
}
$_SESSION["vipnumbers"]=strval($vips);
?>
```

I have a column named vip, and username i want to see the value of vip for username with $unames variable

Comment: I forgot ; in line 3!!!!

Comment: **`Don't use mysql_*`** use PDO or `mysqli_*`

Comment: Take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can simply _read_ what the issue is instead of having to _guess_ or ask here. You simply cannot program in php inside an apache environment without monitoring that log file. Except maybe if you are a big fan of endless blind guessing games.

Comment: Can you tell me where in Cpanel i can see servers error log file.

Comment: Yes it was the semi colon at line 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the semi colon at line 3.

Answer (score 0):

Add semicolon at end of $unames = $_SESSION['username'];

> The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MYSQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions.use prepared statement and avoid sql injection

```
        <?php
       session_start();

       $unames = $_SESSION['username'];
       //db connection example


        $servername = "localhost";  //host name

        $username = "username"; //username

        $password = "password"; //password

        $mysql_database = "dbname"; //database name

      //mysqli prepared statement 

        $link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

       mysqli_select_db($link,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

        $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT vip FROM here_your_tablename WHERE username =?");

                    $stmt->bind_param('s',$unames);

                    $stmt->execute();
                    $get_result =$stmt->get_result();

                    $row =$get_result->fetch_assoc();

                       $vips = $row['vip'];  

                    $stmt->close();
                     $link->close();


     $_SESSION["vipnumbers"]=strval($vips);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a
 `;`

at `$unames = $_SESSION['username']`

Hence the code should be like :

```
<?php
session_start();
$unames = $_SESSION['username'];
$link = mysql_connect( "localhost", "databaseusername", "databasepassword");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);
$vipquery = mysql_query("SELECT vip FROM tablename WHERE username = '$unames'", $link);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($vipquery)) {
    $vips = $row['vip'];  
}
$_SESSION["vipnumbers"]=strval($vips);
?>
```

Secondly, the mysql_connect has been deprecated from php5.5 so it would be good if you shift to

`$conn = mysqli_connect()`

and use $conn for all other operations such as `mysqli_query($conn,QUERY HERE);`
 and so on.